# Sort alphabetically an array taken dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, asort

I have an array obtained from a json, and I want to sort its elements alphabetically.

I have a function that returns me the result of the array:

```
      $cities = get_cities();
```

I tried both:

```
  asort($cities['cities']);
  foreach($cities['cities'] as $rc) { blah blah
```

and

```
  foreach(asort($cities['cities']) as $rc) { blah blah
```

none did not do the sorting.

any idea about where I am wrong?
thanks!

Comment: add the output for print_r($cities);

Comment: Is this an associative array? The man page says asort can be used for associative arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: sorry - the output is: {"cities":[{"name":"Bucure\u015fti","slug":"bucuresti","latitude":"44.437711","longitude":"26.097367"},{"name":"Cluj Napoca","slug":"cluj","latitude":"46.716082","longitude":"23.471831"},{"name":"Bra\u015fov","slug":"brasov","latitude":"45.655651","longitude":"25.610800"},{"name":"Timi\u015foara","slug":"timisoara","latitude":"45.759722","longitude":"21.230000"},{"name":"Constan\u0163a","slug":"constanta","latitude":"44.173333","longitude":"28.638333"},{"name":"Ia\u015fi","slug":"iasi","latitude":"47.156944","longitude":"27.590278"},

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your `$cities` array looks like, it is hard to tell what the problem is.

Have you tried using the just the regular PHP sort function? i.e.

```
sort( $cities );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by city names could look like

```
$c = $cities['cities'];
usort($c, function($cityA, $cityB) { 
    return strcmp($cityA['name'], $cityB['name']);
});
```